# Find $\pi_1(S^3\setminus X)$ and the homology groups of $S^3\setminus X$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=\{(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2|z^5+w^3=0\}$.

a) Show that $\mathbb{C^2}\setminus X$ deformation retracts to $S^3\setminus X$.

b) Find $\pi_1(S^3\setminus X)$ and the homology groups of $S^3\setminus X$.

My Try:

I did part (a). For it I proved that given $(z,w)\in \mathbb{C^2}\setminus X$ there is a unique $\lambda>0$ such that $(\lambda^3z,\lambda^3 w)\in S^3\setminus X$. For part (b) I don't know even how to start. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Are you familiar with torus knots?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see, $X\subset S^3$ is just a torus knot $(3,5)$, because $X$ belongs the torus $|z|=|w|$. The presentation of $\pi_1$ for such knots is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knot_group), in your case it will be $\langle a,b|a^3=b^5\rangle$.

The most easy way to compute homology groups give [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality): it says that $S^3\setminus X$ is homology equivalent to $S^1$ (as in case $X$ be unknot).